# Prove $a_n = 7a_{n-2} + 6a_{n-3}$ for $n\ge 3$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

Let $a_0 = 1$, $a_1 = 1$, and $a_k = 2a_{k-1} + 3a_{k-2}$ for all integers $k\ge 2$.

Prove $a_n = 7a_{n-2} + 6a_{n-3}$ for all $n\ge 3$.

**Proof:**

Let $n\ge 3$ be arbitrary and fixed.

From here, I do not know how to complete the proof, can anybody help me out here please?

Thank you!

Comment: Is the sequence you are working with the Fibonacci sequence?

Comment: Yes it is! Sorry for not including that, my mistake!

Comment: $a_{n}=a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}=(a_{n-2}+a_{n-3})+a_{n-2}=2a_{n-2}+a_{n-3}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $n\ge 3$,

\begin{align}a_n &= 2a_{n-1} + 3a_{n-2}\\
&= 2(2a_{n-2} + 3a_{n-3}) + 3a_{n-2}\\
&= 4a_{n-2} + 6a_{n-3} + 3a_{n-2}\\
&= 7a_{n-2} + 6a_{n-3}.
\end{align}